# scrollTo on object and not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my Jquery code, I want to set the scroll position for the object, however I’m failing in every way I can think of, also seems like scroll to isn't even working

```
function runeServer(){
 $('.vote_content_webpage').html('<object id="webpage" type="text/html" data="http://www.runelocus.com/toplist/index.php?action=vote&&id=20923&data=<?php echo  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" width="100%" height="95%"/>');
 $('#webpage').scrollTo(500);
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you just scroll to a object, instead of pinning a position to a object?

Comment: `scrollTo()` is a jQuery plugin method: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/  If you don't include it, you cannot use it

Answer (score 2):

you can use `scrollTop` rather

```
$('#webpage').scrollTop(500);
```

`scrollTo` is from some jQuery plugin and I think you haven't include the necessary files to support the `scrollTo` function https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *DOM* object instead of jQuery object. Use indexer to convert the jQuery object to DOM object

```
 $('#webpage')[0].scrollTo(500);
```

You can also use [.get( index )](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the `DOM` object

```
$('#webpage').get(0).scrollTo(500);
```

Comment: @zzlalani jquery object is an array like object

Comment: It will return jQuery object like collection as far as I know. I think indexer is fine here